# How do i update swing application view from one screen to another?

Tags: swing

I am a beginner in java swing.
I have just created my first login screen using netbean.
I like to ask after my actionPerformed if say login successfully. How do i actually go to the next screen? As in coding wise how should i code or netbeans got something build in for this

Answer (score 0):

You should have a new class that extends Jframe called something appropriate (MainWindow maybe) that gets created when the user enters the correct password, so probably in the eventListener code for the button

```
if (usernameAndPasswordCorrect()) {
    loginWindow.setVisible(false);
    loginWindow.dispose();
    MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(loginWindow, "Incorrect login information. Try again.");
}
```

Or something like that.